# Update table's column value and showing it at the same time (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, database, syntax-error

First of all, the system I am working on is a virtual HR system. Now, I have this profile.php page where the form for the applicant is located. The form is consists of her/his basic profile and requires him/her to set the skills the applicant has. When the applicant press the submit button, it will go to test.php where the page will display the possible jobs that the applicant is qualified into based on the skills of the applicant that he/she entered in the `profile.php`.

Now, I'm having this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Specialist WHERE fname=Jamie' at line 2
```

Here's the code in the **test.php** where I'm trying to update and show the job column value in employee table.

```
        $last = mysql_query("SELECT * from employee ") or die(mysql_error());

        echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='15' text-align = 'center' >";
        echo "<tr>";

            echo "<th>Name</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $last )){  
                $nym = $row2['fname'];  
            }

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee as t1,jobs as t2
                where t1.skills = t2.skills ") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){
                $jt = $row['jobtitle'];
                $hey = mysql_query("UPDATE employee
                            SET job=$jt
                            WHERE fname=$nym")
                            or die(mysql_error()); 

                echo '<th><b><font color="#663300">' . $row['job'] . '</font></b><br></th>';
        }
```

Here's the snapshot of my employee database
http://snag.gy/i7pw6.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change query like this...

```
 $hey = mysql_query("UPDATE employee
                            SET `job`='$jt'
                            WHERE `fname`='$nym'")
                            or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: This works. Thanks :) Now, I'll just solve another issue where it also shows all the past showed jobs. Well, thanks for this!

Comment: Wait, I got a slight issue with your code. I tried it again and again but it won't show the possible job for the applicant unless the applicant would reload the page. @unique_id

Comment: i just tried to make your query valid may be the problem would be in your logic

Comment: Maybe I'll just figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for a quick fix, change your `while` loop to the following:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){
                $jt = $row['jobtitle'];
                $hey = mysql_query("UPDATE employee
                            SET job='$jt'
                            WHERE fname='$nym'")
                            or die(mysql_error()); 

                echo '<th><b><font color="#663300">' . $row['job'] . '</font></b><br></th>';
        }
```

please note the apostrophes around the $nym variable in the call to `mysql_query`.

I **strongly** advise you to change your queries and query your DB using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Otherwise, your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injectio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)n attacks

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried changing it with your code but I still got the same error.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to also quote the $jt variable in the same query. please try with the edited while and post the error message if it appears

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it using bellow: just set the $nym variable in proper brackets

```
   $hey = mysql_query("UPDATE employee
                        SET job=$jt
                        WHERE fname= '".$nym."')
                        or die(mysql_error());
```